# c program graphics error

Tags: c, dos, bgi, turbo-c

I have implemented the boundary fill algorithm in C language with the following code:--

```
/* WAP to fill the polygon using boundary fill 4 connected algo */

#include "stdio.h"
#include "conio.h"
#include "graphics.h"
#include "dos.h"

void main()
{

    int gd = DETECT, gm;
    clrscr();

    detectgraph(&gd, &gm);
    initgraph(&gd, &gm , "C:\\TC\\BGI");

    rectangle(60,60,500,500);
    boundary_fill(65,65,4,15);
    getch();
    closegraph();
}

boundary_fill(int x, int y, int fclr, int bclr)
{

    if(getpixel(x,y)!= bclr && getpixel(x,y)!= fclr)
    {
        putpixel(x,y,fclr);
        boundary_fill(x+1,y,fclr,bclr);
        boundary_fill(x-1,y,fclr,bclr);
        boundary_fill(x,y+1,fclr,bclr);
        boundary_fill(x,y-1,fclr,bclr);

    }
}
```

when i compile it no error come. But When i run the program the window closes and i get the following error:--
C:\TC\BIN\TC.EXE
The NTVDM CPU has encounterer an illegal instruction.. . . . . .

PLease help

Comment: do you have bgi folder in your turboc?

Comment: Don't run directly any DOS apps in any Windows after XP/Server 2003. Use DosBox at the very least.

Comment: This is not valid C. main() must return int since this is a hosted app. boundary_fill must return a value, and it should have a function prototype. You should include standard library headers using the <stdio.h> syntax, not "stdio.h". **You are not learning C programming correctly because you are using an obsolete, non-standard compiler!**

Answer (score 2):

stop using turboC. run your 16 bit programs(such as TurboC/C++) with DosBox instead. NTVDM error occurs because of 32bit COMMAND-PROMPT trying to run a 16 Bit Program.

Comment: @Vishu Singhvi what did you try?

Comment: I tried to implement the program using DosBox . But the same error is coming.